# KIll user session on window.onunload

Tags: javascript, jsf

I want to kill a users session if they back out of  a certain page.

The problem is apparently  **window.onunload** does not work in chrome or something to that effect. Is there a work around for this where I can kill the session ONLY when the user **backs out** ? Right now if the user backs out, it will give them a prompt which offers them the choice of staying on the page or leaving.

---

client side:

```
<a4j:jsFunction 
    name="killUserSession" 
    action="#{sessionController.invalidateSession()}"/>
```

...........

```
var warning = true;
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
  if (warning) {
    return "You have not filled out the required information below.";
  }
}

window.onunload = function(){
    killUserSession();
}

function setOnloadNull(){
    console.log("Setting onload to null");
    var warning = false;
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

Comment: Although MDN says this event is compatible with Chrome - and you state otherwise -  You can and should handle this event through window.addEventListener() and the unload event.

Comment: @user1428716 I tried window.addEventListener("onunload",killUserSession,false); unfortunately I get the same results , session is not killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check your issue and i found (under chrome) `setOnLoadNull` is the cause of the issue.

[Demo fails.](http://jsfiddle.net/3qKCZ/1/)

But when i disable this method, then the `onunload` works like a charm.

[Demo works.](http://jsfiddle.net/3qKCZ/3/)

Comment: I need the setOnLoadNull  so that when the user submits the form they don't get "Leaving page prompt". setOnLoadNull is only called when the form is submitted.

Comment: In this case do not define window.onbeforeunload method.
Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3qKCZ/4/

Comment: If it's done like that then the prompt is no longer shown when the user backs out of the page and the user session is still not killed.

Comment: Are we agree that you doesn't want to display the prompt and that killUserSession(); must be called?
In this case my sample jsfiddle.net/3qKCZ/4 do that (console.log('aaaaa') is done so if you replace that statement by a call to your function it will be called).
If it still doesn't work, i think that is your killUserSession(); that doesn't do the job.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. I want to kill the user session and show the prompt only if the user tries to back out of the page. If  the user does not back out the page and submits the form then I don't want to show the prompt.

Comment: How do you define 'to back ou the page'?
User hit the back button of the browser?

Comment: Yes : "user hits the back button"